# Why did the Owl in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone want money, and why don't other birds demand money too?

Tags: harry-potter

*Very* closely related (but not identical): [In Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone, Hagrid's Owl Wanted Payment. Do Owls Use Wizard Money?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158617/in-harry-potter-and-the-philosophers-stone-hagrids-owl-wanted-payment-do-owl)

In *Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone*, an owl demanded payment from Hagrid for delivering a message. However, there's no record (that I'm aware of) in the series of any other bird demanding money.

The linked question is about why that particular owl wanted payment. (Actually, I'm wondering the same thing and think that there could be more detailed answers there, but that's a separate question). My question is - why does this only appear in *Philosopher's Stone*? Sure, Harry's owl wanted food and other rewards, but why don't any other birds demand money - why just that one?

Comment: also remember, the HP series (at this time) is all from Harry's perspective. Things that are new will be called out as they occur, but may not necessarily be "noticed" again, instead, Harry just integrates these news things into his worldview

Comment: I find it humorous to think of the bird itself wanting the money, not just collecting on someone else's behalf

Comment: This is how they make a collect call.

Comment: They do - you just must not have dated enough.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The owl wasn't delivering a message. It was instead delivering a newspaper,  the Daily Prophet. The Daily Prophet offers a subscription service that apparently requires you to pay for each copy of the paper daily, rather than paying upfront.

The owl only "demanded" money because it hadn't been paid, and it needed to be. There are other instances in the books of owls delivering copies of the Daily Prophet and being paid (you'll have to take this on faith right now as I don't have access to the books). It seems reasonable to assume that, had they not been paid, they also would have made attempts to obtain payment.

There's another, slightly related, example of an owl "demanding" something from the recipient of a message. At the beginning of Order of the Phoenix Harry sends a message, and tells Hedwig to make sure that the recipient (Ron and/or Hermione, if I recall correctly) responds with actual news about what's been happening. We later find out that Hedwig fulfilled that request.

Comment: +1, the way I see it the owls are asking for money only because their owners told them to. And people don't usually tell their owls to ask for money because it'd be incredibly rude.

Comment: You can see [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/56464/73718) answer for places where it's mentioned that Hermione paid for Daily Prophet newspapers.

Comment: I'm now imagining email-style-scams via owl-post... "Dear friend, I've recently come into a great deal of money, but I am unable to reach Gringotts due to an unfortunate case of dragonpox. Please deposit the cheque attached to this owl into your account and send half of the money back with it, so that I may pay for my treatment. You may keep the other half of the money as a reward."

Comment: To support this, I definitely remember some bits in book 5 or 6 when Hermione starts getting the Daily Prophet, and she asks Harry to give the owl its money.

Comment: @tonysdg That's what Sneakoscopes are for.

Comment: @tonysdg Given that HP world does not seem to have even arbitrage on gold and silver I doubt they have checks.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I'm sure a long lost prince will find a way to leverage what ever financial tools are available.

Comment: @tonysdg At some point Magical Britain might have to ask Magical Nigeria to put a stop to such shenanigans.

Comment: Doesn't Hagrid saying that the owl "wants payin’ fer deliverin’ the paper" sort of contradict your assumption that the payment was for the subscription of the paper? it certainly appears that the payment is specifically for its **delivery**

Answer (score 55):

As Anthony said, the payment is for the subscription of The Daily Prophet. We see this happen a couple times in the books.

> ‘Hagrid!’ said Harry loudly. ‘There’s an owl –’
>
> ‘Pay him,’ Hagrid grunted into the sofa.
>
> ‘What?’
>
> ‘**He wants payin’ fer deliverin’ the paper.** Look in the pockets.’
>
> Hagrid’s coat seemed to be made of nothing but pockets – bunches of
>   keys, slug pellets, balls of string, mint humbugs, tea-bags … finally,
>   Harry pulled out a handful of strange-looking coins.
>
> ‘Give him five Knuts,’ said Hagrid sleepily.
>
> ‘Knuts?’
>
> ‘The little bronze ones.’
>
> **Harry counted out five little bronze coins and the owl held out its
>   leg so he could put the money into a small leather pouch tied to it.**
>   <sub>The Philosopher's Stone - Chapter 5: Diagon Alley</sub>

> Hermione, however, had to move her orange juice aside quickly to make
>   way for a large damp barn owl bearing a sodden Daily Prophet in its
>   beak.
>
> ‘What are you still getting that for?’ said Harry irritably, thinking
>   of Seamus as **Hermione placed a Knut in the leather pouch on the owl’s
>   leg** and it took off again.
>   <sub>The Order of the Phoenix - Chapter 12: Professor Umbridge</sub>

<sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

It is not mentioned every time a subscription of The Daily Prophet shows up because it doesn't need to be. Rowling established that you pay a few (between 1 and 5 apparently) Knuts for the subscription, and trusted that the reader would remember that. This information is worldbuilding, but not really integral to the plot, so it's not mentioned every time.

The rest of the time we see owls being used as messengers, it's either Hedwig/Pig whose job is to do whatever Harry/Ron wants. Or it's a school owl that also has to do what they want. The owls themselves could not care less about the money. They just want food and care. So long as they get that, they seem to be willing to ferry mail around.

Comment: I guess Hermione gets a student discount?

Comment: @MissMonicaE Or that owl just hates Hagrid and charges him five time as much as everybody else.

Comment: Maybe Hagrid pays for a week at a time instead? Or (non-universe explanation) - JKR forgot how much she said a subscription was supposed to cost?

Comment: Or maybe the owl was confused about the price? ;)

Comment: Was it, perhaps, a weekend edition? They often cost more.

Comment: Upvote for actual quotes as evidence! :)

Comment: @MissMonicaE or the owl knows to charge more for flying to a barren island in a raging storm

Comment: Maybe there's a discount for water damage.

Comment: Maybe Hagrid is a generous tipper.  Especially after the owl had to go through so much to get to Hagrid.  Hagrid was more of a fan of the paper while paying for it than Hermoine was!  The owl don't seem to specify the amount, Hagrid tells him how much and could have included the tip in is calculations.

Comment: @Christy he also tells Harry how many knuts to tip. Given that he seems to have extreme amnesia about the fact that Harry didn't grow up in a magical household, and doesn't really seem to understand what Harry does and doesn't know, the fact that he tells him how many knuts to give him, the first time, seems significant.

Comment: @AdamV JKR is notoriously "awful at maths", so I'd be inclined to believe the latter.

Comment: @MontyHarder I find being bad at maths a horrible excuse for not being able to tell apart 1 and 5 though :/